# Chrome external extension gives error "CRX_REQUIRED_PROOF_MISSING"

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium, crx

I have created chrome extension by using crx3 command. I have downloaded crx3 from [npmjs.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crx3)
I have uploaded this new crx file on our internal server and trying to install it. But it is giving me error message

> Package is Invalid: 'CRX_REQUIRED_PROOF_MISSING'.

If any one have any idea how we can distribute the external extension please let me know.

Comment: Things to try: 1) use the built-in Pack button on `chrome://extensions` page, 2) to install a local crx file you need to use policies like ExtensionInstallForcelist or install it as explained in [this answer](/a/38011386), 3) see what happens in https://crbug.com/993326

Comment: I have tried to pack the extension from chrome://extensions and tested this newly created extension on Mac OS Mojave and observed the same error.

Comment: Chrome doesn't allow the installation of crx (packaged extensions) from outside of Chrome web store.